# How does account creation work?

Tags: accounts

I'm interacting with `stellar-core` alone without any SDK/Horizon support. I've created a private network with 5 nodes, each a validator node requiring 2/3 of the 5 nodes to agree.

I'm a bit confused as to how account creation works. The documentation doesn't really touch on how accounts are created without SDK support. I'm assuming the account information is a just a public key correlated with the private keys thats held by the account owner, and I'm further assuming that an account gets registered with **one** peer and that peer sends this account creation operation to the network for consensus, it is then stored somewhere on **all** the peers.

My questions is, are my assumptions true? And **how** exactly do I create an account (i.e. what commands do I need and how do I use that command)?

---

UPDATE: I managed to create a transaction containing a `createAccount` operation through stellar-lab and I tried submitting the transaction using the command `--c \tx?blob=BASED64`, but I'm getting the error `GBVQ6 [default INFO] {"status": "ERROR" , "error": "AAAAAAAAAAD////3AAAAAA=="}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

Accounts are created by submitting a signed transaction to the network, a transaction containing a `createAccount` operation.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#create-account

https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#creating-an-account

Comment: I saw that but my question was how to send a transaction containing a `createAccount` operation **without** SDK support. i.e. using nothing but stellar-core

Comment: You can't. You have to generate the XDR blob somehow. That's done by the SDK.

Comment: *Sending* it isn't complicated, that's just the `/tx?blob={base-64 blocb}` endpoint of your stellar-core node

Comment: Do you mean that as a statement about the transaction's reply message? As in one can send a transaction via `/tx` endpoint but not necessarily receive any useful information about it?

Comment: It's an asynchronous interface. It tells you if it's a transaction already submitted, or if there's an error with it.

If you want *better* sending support, that's Horizon.

Comment: Where is Horizon getting the "better" information from? The database?